# Trying to uninstall Adobe. I am trying to delete a directory in Program Files x86 and it keep saying 'permission denied'. What do I do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I had a question regarding deleting a directory/uninstalling a software fully. So I downloaded Adobe Creative Cloud to do UI work and the launcher won't even work. So I decided to just delete every single file related to Adobe. I'm thinking of deleting the program Files (x86) directory and the Adobe directory in AppData/Local (idk what other directory to delete). How do I do it?

When I try using the `Remove-Item` command with the `-Force` flag nothing damn works and it just throws a million 'permission denied' errors. Please help. *And yes I right clicked and opened in administrator.*

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" -Force

Confirm
The item at C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all
 children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AdobeCollabSync.exe: Access to
the path 'AdobeCollabSync.exe' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (AdobeCollabSync.exe:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AXE8SharedExpat.dll: Access to
the path 'AXE8SharedExpat.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Your brute-force method is highly inadvisable and may damage your installation of windows. With complex programs, companies make cleaning tools for situations like this. Adobe is no different. You can download and run their cleaning tool to fix your problem here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html